# Should I order references on surname or paper title when using Harvard style?

Tags: citations

I use the harvard referencing style.
One of our assignment instructions is:

> The reference list should be in alphabetical order

Lets use the following references as an example

> Kopecky, J. and Simperl, E., 2008. Semantic Web Service Offer
>   Discovery for E-commerce.
>
> Sanvido, F., Sanchez, D., Mendoza, A. and Lopez, A., 2011. Dynamic
>   Negotiation Layer for Secure Semantic Service Oriented Architectures.

Following the instruction I was given to order the references, is it generally implied that I should order the references by the first authors surname: Kopecky then Sanvido.
Or is it implied that I should order by the paper titles: "Dynamic Negotiation Layer..." then "Semantic Web Service..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Harvard website](http://isites.harvard.edu/icb/icb.do?keyword=k70847&pageid=icb.page363223):

> The entries in the list should be in **alphabetical order by the
>   author's last name [sic]**.

As pointed out by aeismail in the comment, the second criterion is the date:

> Works by the same author should be ordered chronologically, from oldest to most recent

Of course, you might have many articles with the **same author and same year**, in that case, they say that:

> If your reference list includes multiple works by the same author in
>   the same year, identify them in your parenthetical citations and in
>   your reference list by a lowercase letter after the year, assigning
>   each letter in alphabetical order by the title of the work

Comment: That instruction should really be "_authors'_ last names," since it's not just the first author's last name that gets used in the alphabetization process. Year should be the second sorting criterion.

Comment: @aeismail Thanks for pointing out that I missed the 'Year' as sorting criterion. But thank you so much more for allowing me to add a (sic) on a quote from Harvard website.

Comment: I sic'ed your [sic]—it should have gone after "name." :-) [And, even more entertainingly, the sample that website shows doesn't even follow _that_ rule correctly, as two articles are listed out of order!]

Comment: Just as an addendum, even outside Harvard style referencing, it is typical to use the same sorting order.